# Change tcp_rmem and tcp_wmem

Tags: tcp, throughput

how is the smallest value for tcp_rmem_default and tcp_wmem_default? Becauase im doing tcp tuning and my windows size is 6250 bytes (10mbit bandwith, delay 5ms and loss %0.00001) so i put tcp_rmem_default='6250' and tcp_wmem_default='6250' but it didn't work and decreased troughput. Then i put tcp_rmem_default='65536' and tcp_wmem_default='65536'and increase the Throughput, but this value default. Also i calculate windows size with 10mbit bandwith and delay 5ms and the result was 6250 bytes! So i can't understand! I hope someone can help me! Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I calculate windows size with 10mbit bandwith and delay 5ms and the result was 6250 byte

No it isn't.

```
bandwidth = 10Mbits/s = 10*1024*1024/8 bytes/s = 1310720 bytes/s
delay = 5ms = 0.005s
product = 1310720*0.005 = 6553.6
```

However 6250 is far too small for a TCP send or receive buffer, and has been for many years. Linux probably agrees and enforces a higher minimum.